# Null uri when i delete the file and i try to save it again

Tags: java, android, image, layout

I am trying to save all the content of a **screen** in **image** format, for this in my `layout` I have a `LinearLayout` where all the other elements are added.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/creado"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Then, it is created:

```
private LinearLayout contenido;
```

And called in the `onCreate()` method:

```
contenido = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.creado);
```

To store all the content of the `Layout`, I use the `setOnLongClickListener` event:

```
    contenido.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            if(permissionHelper.hasPermission()){
                saveImage(VistaPrevia.this);
            }else{
                ejecutar();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

To save it I do the following methods:

```
private void GuardarLayout(Context context){//method to save
    contenido.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    contenido.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bmap = contenido.getDrawingCache();
    try {
        saveImage(bmap);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } finally {
        contenido.destroyDrawingCache();
    }
}

private void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
        ContentValues values = contentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Pictures/" + "Genshin Impact Mis Builds");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, true);
        Uri uri = this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        if (uri != null) {
            Log.d("HOLAIF", "saveImage: " + uri.toString());
            try {
                saveImageToStream(bitmap, this.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri));
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, false);
                this.getContentResolver().update(uri, values, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(this, "¡Se ha guardado tu build de manera exitosa!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } else {
        File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + '/' + getString(R.string.app_name));
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdirs();
        }
        String fileName = nombrePersonaje + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(directory, fileName);
        try {
            saveImageToStream(bitmap, new FileOutputStream(file));
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
            this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

private ContentValues contentValues() {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, nombrePersonaje + ".jpg");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/*");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
    return values;
}

private void saveImageToStream(Bitmap bitmap, OutputStream outputStream) {
    if (outputStream != null) {
        try {
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that after saving one, it won't let me save others. I mean, I can save one. When I want to keep another one, it won't let me. This problem is reflected when I close and reopen the app. I can only save it once and then it doesn't save anymore. When i save for first time the `layout` here `uri` isn't `null`:

[image]

But when i close the app and started again, i can't save and `uri` is `null`

[image]

Why does the `Uri` become `null`? What am I writing wrong in the code? From already thank you very much

**UPDATE**

I discovered that the problem with my code is what i delete the file saved. That's  when the file is saved, so i'm going to search the file in your repesctive location and i delete it,  then i'm going to my app and i was try to save it again and here's when the uri get null. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error mainly depends upon ContentProvider

Find the working code below =>

```
private File saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
    try {
        File path =new File(
                this.getFilesDir(),
                getString(R.string.app_name)
        );
        if (!path.exists()) {
            path.mkdirs();
        }

        String fileName = "filename.png";

        File outFile =new File(path, fileName);
        if (!outFile.exists()) {
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 70, outputStream);
            outputStream.close();
        }
        return outFile;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Make sure to verify provider_path.xml

```
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="0"
        path="." />

</paths>
```

Comment: or what's val? when i write val: `Cannot resolve symbol 'val'`

Comment: Yes, it is kotlin